# Hashtable in python by file

Tags: python, hash

I want to implement a hash table in python from a file txt. My file is something like `example.txt`:

```
aaa.12
bbb.14
ccc.10
```

I can open this file in python but I don't know how to import each line in a hash table built like hash:

```
{'aaa':12, 'bbb':14, 'ccc':10}
```

ok thank you very much. another question..if i want to order the value and save in the file the items in order how can i do? 
i try to use this: 
after your code i save the values 
v=sorted(hash.values()) 
and to check it if worked i print v so the result was this: v =[10, 14, 14].  So it works. but know how can i change the orginal file example.txt and save in this order:
ccc.10
aaa.12
bbb.14

Comment: Please include some code to show what you tried.

Answer (score 3):

Provided the `aaa.12`, etc. items are each on a separate line:

```
with open('example.text') as f:
    hash = {}
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split('.', 1)
        hash[key] = int(value)
```

Note that you probably mean the `dict` type, which is a specific kind of python mapping, that happens to use a hash table in the underlying implementation.

Comment: ok thank you very much. another question..if i want to order the value and save in the file the items in order how can i do?

Comment: @user1841492: use a new post to ask more questions; your question is a little vague in any case for me to answer.